# mpld3: How to change the location of the toolbar using a plugin?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, matplotlib, mpld3

The toolbar for mpld3 displays is usually located in the bottom right corner of the screen. I would like it to be in the top-right corner of the screen. It appears as though the code controlling the position of the toolbar can be located [here](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/blob/cec043807d18d788221455f1933f2cc7099f794e/src/toolbar/toolbar.js#L55).

I would like to know how to select the toolbar object using Javascript so that I may change it's location. The Javascript code would ideally be the attribute of some custom mpld3 plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple `mpld3` plugin to move the toolbar to the top of a figure:

```
class TopToolbar(plugins.PluginBase):
    """Plugin for moving toolbar to top of figure"""

    JAVASCRIPT = """
    mpld3.register_plugin("toptoolbar", TopToolbar);
    TopToolbar.prototype = Object.create(mpld3.Plugin.prototype);
    TopToolbar.prototype.constructor = TopToolbar;
    function TopToolbar(fig, props){
        mpld3.Plugin.call(this, fig, props);
    };

    TopToolbar.prototype.draw = function(){
      // the toolbar svg doesn't exist
      // yet, so first draw it
      this.fig.toolbar.draw();

      // then change the y position to be
      // at the top of the figure
      this.fig.toolbar.toolbar.attr("y", 2);

      // then remove the draw function,
      // so that it is not called again
      this.fig.toolbar.draw = function() {}
    }
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_ = {"type": "toptoolbar"}
```

You can see it in action in [a notebook here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/e8000969652f6a967279).